# Express.js not responding when using session

Tags: node.js, session, redis, express

Here is my app:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer(),
    RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

app.configure (function(){
    app.use (express.logger({ format: ":method :url" }));
    app.use (express.bodyParser());
    app.use (express.cookieParser());
    app.use (express.session({ store: new RedisStore, secret: "totally random string" }));
});
app.configure ('development', function () {
    console.log ("Development mode.");
});
app.configure ('production', function () {
    console.log ("Production mode.");
});

app.get ('/', function (req, res) {
    res.contentType("text/html");
    res.send("hello", 200);
    res.end();
})

console.log ("Listening to *:"+8006);
app.listen (8006);
```

It hangs in the browser when I use localhost:8006/

Any idea whats wrong? I am probably missing 1 little detail.
It works when the `app.use (express.session...` line is commented out

Thanks

Comment: What version of express are you using? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `res.end()` and it stops the hanging and renders the page.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.configure (function(){
    app.use (express.logger({ format: ":method :url" }));
    app.use (express.bodyParser());
    app.use (express.cookieParser());
});

app.configure ('development', function () {
    console.log ("Development mode.");
});
app.configure ('production', function () {
    console.log ("Production mode.");
});

app.get ('/', function (req, res) {
    res.contentType("text/html");
    res.send("hello");
})

console.log ("Listening to *:"+8006);
app.listen (8006);
```

Comment: Just to clarify a little, the reason for this is that `res.send` is a method added to node's `http.ServerResponse` class by Express, whereas `res.end` is a native method. Among other things, `res.send` invokes `res.end` when it's done, and invoking `res.end` yourself afterwards gets you into trouble, since it wasn't designed to be invoked twice (in fact, the response object is probably no longer valid by that time).

Comment: Thank you. It made sense to 'end' the connection like doing so without express.. Saved hours for me, thx